# schroot is giving error on centos 6

Tags: centos, chroot

When I'm using command: `schroot -c 32bit -- bash --login -c "rm -rf ~/SC32 ;"`
I'm getting these errors:
**E: 20copyfiles: cp: cannot create regular file `/var/lib/schroot/mount/32bit-dcc62f68-de18-4d2a-95d9-b71f0be314ce/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory

E: 32bit-dcc62f68-de18-4d2a-95d9-b71f0be314ce: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-start**
Since i'm new to Linux Environment i don't know what to do to solve this error.
The Cent OS which I'm using is 6.3 with x64 architecture 
Also i have configured 32bit in /etc/schroot/schroot.conf as

```
[32bit]  
type=directory  
description=CentOS 6.3 32bit  
directory=/chroot/32bit  
users=temp  
root-groups=root  
personality=linux32
```

Also I Have this directory available /chroot/32bit
I'm not the root user of the system.
Can anybody tell me what to do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

To debug problems with schroot, try running it verbosely:

```
schroot -v
```

or to make it *really* verbose

```
schroot -v --debug=notice
```

The actual failure here is to copy `/etc/resolv.conf`.  There are two potential reasons for this

1. The source file isn't copyable.  Normally unlikely, but try `cp` and `cat` by hand to check.
2. The destination doesn't exist.  This is the usual cause of such errors.

Your chroot is `/chroot/32bit` and it's being (bind) mounted on `/var/lib/schroot/mount/32bit-dcc62f68-de18-4d2a-95d9-b71f0be314ce`.  If `/chroot/32bit/etc` does not exist, then `/var/lib/schroot/mount/32bit-dcc62f68-de18-4d2a-95d9-b71f0be314ce/etc` won't exist either, and so the copy operation will fail.  You *must* have a proper system available under /chroot/32bit with all the usual directories (/bin, /etc, /lib etc.).

Assuming that you *do* have a proper chroot in `/chroot/32bit`, then something has gone wrong during setup.  Running with verbose or debug messages enabled may shed some light on the cause of the failure.

Regards,
Roger
(schroot author)

Comment: Thanks for the attention and posting Roger. Nothing better than getting the author's take :-)

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Roger 's solution and all is well. But I found another workaround solution:

Enter your schroot directory, maybe like this location: `/chroot/32bit`, you can find this path in "`/etc/schroot/schroot.conf`" setting file.

1. cd /chroot/32bit
2. mv /chroot/32bit/etc/resolv.conf /chroot/32bit/etc/resolv.conf.bk

Then you can try your schroot login command and check is success.

1. schroot -c 32bit
2. (32bit)WDan@linux-buildy01:~$
3. Enjoy it!